# How do I perform a simple join on multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have what I'm sure is quite a remedial question here, but I can't for the life of me get this simple join to work.

Basically, I have 3 tables:

- MEMBERS (first_name,last_name),
- MEMBER_TO_GROUP(member_id,group_id)
- PAYMENTS (member_id, date, amount).

I'm looking to grab all payments from members in a specific group. By using only two of the tables, I can find all PAYMENTS of a specific group, without MEMBER information, or I can find all MEMBER information without PAYMENT information.  However, when I attempt to add the third table,  bad data is returned (e.g. I get members not in the group).  This is the basic query i'm using:

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    m.first_name,
    m.last_name
FROM
    members m,
    payments p,
    member_to_group mg
WHERE
    mg.group_id = 12
    AND mg.member_id = p.member_id
    AND m.member_id = p.member_id
```

I'm not sure where the disconnect is, but any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: Get into the habit of using ANSI join syntax (like in galador's answer). It is easier to read and often highlights your logical errors.

Comment: @Nick, this is SQL89. Explicit JOIN is SQL92... :-)

Comment: Implicit joins such as the ones used here are a SQL antipattern. This bad syntax was replaced in 1992 with something easier to read and maintain and far less likely to have accidental cross joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should get what you want:

```
SELECT p.*,
       m.first_name,
       m.last_name
FROM payments p
INNER JOIN members m
  ON m.member_id = p.member_id
INNER JOIN member_to_group mg
  ON mg.member_id = m.member_id
WHERE mg.group_id = 12
```